# TomEE/openEJB and log4j - Ignored property overrides property ... log4.configurationFile?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j2, apache-tomee, openejb

I am trying to create an application with an own SSL provider in a separate library JAR in TomEE+. The JAR is using and configuring log4j2 via "-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=/path/to/log4j2.xml". The first log messages come out fine, but then I get a really weird message that I don't understand and haven't found an explanation on the web:

```
Jun 13, 2016 2:43:02 PM org.apache.openejb.config.MBeanDeployer <clinit>
WARNING: Log4j not installed. The following properties will be ignored.
Jun 13, 2016 2:43:02 PM org.apache.openejb.config.MBeanDeployer <clinit>
WARNING: Ignored Property overrides property 'log4j.configurationFile'
```

After that, log4j does its bare minimum default logging, which is not what I need.

The log4j2 libraries are deployed in the tomcat/lib folder, as is the custom code that needs the logging.

The same way did work for a plain tomcat in a previous project, but not in tomee+ (which we need for other reasons now)

For reference, we're using tomee-plus-1.7.4.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some log4j 1.x properties in conf/logging.properties

TomEE detects it and tries to use log4j1 and identify the setup will not work and logs it.